# Linq to SQL query to find partial duplicates

Tags: c#, t-sql, linq-to-sql

I have looked at lots of SO questions regarding Linq to SQL and duplicates but couldn't find anything that leads me in the right direction for my situation.

I have a view that I want to query to return only rows that have the same ColumnA but a different ColumnB.

MyView

- ID
- ColumnA
- ColumnB

I can get all the values of ColumnA with the following T-SQL query...

```
select
a.ColumnA, COUNT(*)
from 
(
    select
    b.ColumnA, b.ColumnB
    from MyView b
    group by b.ColumnA, b.ColumnB
) a
group by a.ColumnA
having count(*) > 1
```

..but would like to translate to Linq to SQL and also return the ID column as well, if possible.

Any help appreciated.

NB. ASP.NET 4.0, C#, Linq to SQL, SQL Server in use.

**UPDATED**

Sample data:

ID, ColumnA, ColumnB
1, AAA, A100
2, AAA, A100
3, AAA, B200
4, BBB, C300
5, BBB, C300

Desired result:

ID, ColumnA, ColumnB
1, AAA, A100
2, AAA, A100
3, AAA, B200

(As column A are all the same, but ColumnB is different. ID 4 and 5 are not returned as ColumnB values are the same.)

**UPDATED 2**

Somehow I created the following query that does part of what I wanted which is to return just the ColumnA value. Any improvements or suggestions on getting the ID as well appreciated.

```
List<string> duplicates = (from a in
                               (from b in dc.MyTables
                                group b by new { b.ColumnA, b.ColumnB } into c
                                select new
                                {
                                    ColumnA = c.Key.ColumnA,
                                    ColumnB = c.Key.ColumnB
                                })
                           group a by a.ColumnA into d
                           where d.Count() > 1
                           select d.Key).ToList();
```

Comment: Some sample input data plus data you are expecting as out put

Comment: @TheGameiswar - added sample and desired results. Thanks.

Comment: Column B values for id 1,2 are also the same,why are you expecting them

Comment: @TheGameiswar - I need the query to return any row where there is duplication of ColumnA but there is one or more ColumnB values that are different. Worst case I could settle for just knowing the ColumnA values and then I can do additional queries to get all rows that have that value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question, this seemed to be the only solution I could come up with...

```
var duplicates = (from z in dc.MyTables
                  where (from a in
                             (from b in dc.MyTables
                              group b by new { b.ColumnA, b.ColumnB } into c
                              select new
                              {
                                  ColumnA = c.Key.ColumnA,
                                  ColumnB = c.Key.ColumnB
                              })
                             group a by a.ColumnA into d
                             where d.Count() > 1
                             select d.Key).Contains(z.ColumnA)
                      orderby z.ColumnA ascending
                      select new
                      {
                          ID = z.ID,
                          ColumnA = z.CourseUrl2,
                          ColumnB = z.ColumnB
                      }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Doing this is SQL is tricky because you are basically asking to have the list of ID's as a subgroup showing up as one column for each value of A. This is not really relational. It could be accomplished using the famous XML trick to create a concatenated string with all the ID values.

However in LINQ what you are asking for is fairly easy, because you are not limited to a flat row. You can generate a result where the first value is a string, and the second is a List for example. So you can generate a result where each unique ColumnA is field 1 and field 2 would be a List of ID's. This can be done by using the GroupBy Into. Take a look at the LINQ documentation or examples and you should have no problem adapting it to your data.